# How to extract the .dump file?

Tags: svn

I got a file with extention .dump from my supervisor and he said I have to extract it to use it. He said it is realated to SVN(Subversion). I have to extract it to get some source code, to work on. Can anyone help me. I try to use some SVN(subversion) software but I can't extract it. After searching through the internet I think this .dump file is not even related to SVN. Help me.

Comment: Perhaps you should just ask your supervisor?

Comment: haha.. it is like a test to me.. if I ask him, he will think I am not able to do it. So my reputation will go down. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Subversion dump file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) is used to create a backup of a Subversion repository. You will need to ['load'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) it into a repository in order to use it.

If you need to make some changes to some code which is stored in a repository it would be much easier to checkout the repository, make your changes and then commit them in the way that is standard with Subversion workflows. More info on that [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html).